# Script works only with base64 and cannot link to direct file location

Tags: javascript, css, html

hello I have this script that i am using to check an image for transparent pixels but when i try to link the image in html src="filename.png" the script is not working and not finding any transparent pixels. The script works fine if i imput base64 encoding for the image. Ideally I would like to have the option just to link the image from the directory. Can you pint point the direction i need to go? Thanks

```
<img src="WORKS ONLY BASE64" alt="Sample image" id="img" />


(function () {
var img = new Image(),
    output = document.getElementById('transparent'),
    bImg = document.getElementById('img');
    img.src = bImg.src;

function isTransparent(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
        y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('imgcheck-canvas') || (function (_this) {
        var e = document.createElement('canvas');
        e.setAttribute('width', _this.width);
        e.setAttribute('height', _this.height);
        e.setAttribute('id', _this.id + '-canvas');
        e.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        document.body.appendChild(e);
        var cx = e.getContext('2d');
        cx.drawImage(_this, 0, 0, _this.width, _this.height);
        return e;
    })(this);
    if (canvas.getContext === undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    output.innerHTML = ((ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[3] === 0) ? true : false);
}

function init() {
    console.log('init');
    bImg.addEventListener('mousemove', isTransparent, true);
}

img.addEventListener('load', init, true);


})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P2TJA/

Comment: The fiddle you posted reports `false` ... it looks  to me as if your code only checks one pixel of the image for transparency.

Comment: You also need to wait for the image to load.

Comment: What do you mean? It catches correctly every transparent and non-transprent pixel? Is transparent: false means its opaque non-transparent? Can you clarify what did u ment?

Edit: after a image is linked it reports false doesn't this means that the script is not finding any transparent pixels at all?